# Update one column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables. wp_users and wp_users_backup. It just a copy. The tables look like this:

```
wp_users
user_login|user_pass
user1     |pasword94545
user2     |pasword5920
```

The column user_pass has a different value. How can I update the column user_pass from wp_users_backup where user_login = equal in to the table wp_users?

Comment: Please use the search feature on the website to look for similar problems. StackOverflow helps if you have a piece of code that needs help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few ways to do that:
1: using table expression

```
    With ABC
    AS
    (
    select a.user_login, a.user_pass as old, b.user_pass as new
    from wp_users inner as a join wp_users_backup as b
    on b.user_login = a.user_login
    )
    Update ABC
    SET ABC.old = ABC.new
```

2.using correlated query

```
Update wp_users as a
set user_pass = (select user_pass from wp_users_backup as b where b.user_login = a.user_login )
```

Comment: @Badslayer glad I could help, I updated the first one, one syntax error

Comment: I missed the 'AS' after defining the table expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_users_backup
SET user_pass = 
(SELECT user_pass FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = wp_users_backup.user_login);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to restore the values from the backup table,
so, you can do it with a update join:

```
UPDATE wp_users a 
    JOIN wp_users_backup  b ON a.user_login = b.user_login
SET a.user_pass = b.user_pass
```